# center a Bootstrap column when resolution is under 767

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

the site: http://orbayaar.co.il/index/

I'm trying to make the cols in "div.row.windows" align center when resolution is under 767.

I have tried to give them "margin:auto", but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: not understood your problem..can you be more specific because everthing is already showing in center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that using the offset class: `.col-xs-6 .col-xs-offset-3` would maken the column 6/12th wide and give it a offset (from the left) of 3/12

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wietsedevries/r3crsf7j/2/